# Write to .m-file

Tags: matlab

I Would like to write a copyright statement to each `.m`-file in my folders. The statement should be:

an empty line

"Copyright blablabla"

an empty line

I wish that these three lines are added after the first function-statement-line which is always at line 1. I can gather all the files and call them so the question regards how I should

- Read the file
- Add the three lines
- write the new `.m`-file

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a specific problem that you are having? Have you looked at the documentation? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/index.html#data-and-file-management

Comment: You could do this in almost any language (including Matlab itself).  What is the specific issue?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The specific issue is how it can be done in the Matlab programming language.

Comment: Ok.  But you can be more specific.  Is the problem opening a file, reading a file, appending the data, or what?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Ok. If there is a way to read the data into cell arrays, one string for each line it would be easy to add the lines and write the data afterwards. But I did not find any way to do that.

Comment: ok found: fid = fopen(`myFile.ext`)
allData = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');

Answer (score 0):

You use the comment symbol which is `%`, although you definitely have to check the manual and some online tutorial as well, to get familiarized